# Image path for EXIFInterface

Tags: android

I use this code to get an image's path and then try to get it's EXIF data to check rotation but the code crashes with the message
"Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /external/images/media/12729 (No such file or directory)" at line

```
val ei = selectedImage.path?.let { ExifInterface(it) }
```

My code is

```
fun getImagepath(activity: Activity): Uri? {
    val uriExternal: Uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    val cursor: Cursor?
    val imageId: Long
    val columnIndexID: Int
    val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
    cursor = activity.contentResolver.query(uriExternal, projection, null, null, null)
    return if (cursor != null) {
        columnIndexID = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
        cursor.moveToLast()
        imageId = cursor.getLong(columnIndexID)
        val uriImage = Uri.withAppendedPath(uriExternal, "" + imageId)
        cursor.close()
        uriImage
    } else {
        null
    }
}

private fun rotateImageIfRequired(img: Bitmap, selectedImage: Uri): Bitmap {
    val ei = selectedImage.path?.let { ExifInterface(it) }
    when (ei?.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL)) {
        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 -> {
            return rotateImage(img, 90)
        }
        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180 -> {
            return rotateImage(img, 180)
        }
        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270 -> {
            return rotateImage(img,270)
        }
    }
    return img
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are using [the Jetpack edition of `ExifInterface`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/exifinterface/media/ExifInterface). Then, replace:

```kotlin
val ei = selectedImage.path?.let { ExifInterface(it) }
```

with:

```kotlin
val ei = ExifInterface(activity.contentResolver.openInputStream(selectedImage))
```

And please stop trying to get a path from a `Uri`.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare. I am not using Jetpack so I guess I'd better update.
When you advise to stop trying to get a path from a Uri are you saying I should implement my getImagepath function differently?

Comment: @Peter: "I am not using Jetpack" -- it has been around for several years at this point. "are you saying I should implement my getImagepath function differently" -- no, I am saying that you should not call `getPath()` on a `Uri` (either using method-call syntax or, in Kotlin, using the `path` synthetic property, as you are doing in `selectedImage.path`).

Comment: Thanks again @Commonsware. I am using jetpack, just didn't realise it.
Your answer fixed my rotation issue from the camera (on a Samsung), I just now need to do the same for a stored image.